# phantomjs - css transform rotate

Tags: javascript, html, css, webkit, phantomjs

I have a webpage I want to print.
for that I am using `phantomjs`.

In the following example you will notice a strange effect.
non of the rotated text has been rendered correctly

I cant seem to get my head around how this can happen,
chrome is rendering this perfectly and `phantomjs-webpage` userAgent is set to webkit.

This is the link I'm trying to capture:

http://www.facegift.co.il/canvas/print.aspx?userItemId=27477&Sc=974088&pagenum=3&width=1500&print=2

This is the image that's been rendered:
[image]

and This is my code example:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
var args = require('system').args;

var isLoad = false;

page.settings.userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.120 Safari/537.36';

page.viewportSize = { width: 500, height: 687.5 };

page.open('http://www.facegift.co.il/canvas/print.aspx?userItemId=27477&Sc=974088&pagenum=3&width=1500&print=2', function (status) {
var ue = page.evaluate(function () {
    return window.navigator.appVersion;
});
console.log("status: " + status);
console.log("ue: " + ue);

if (status === "success") {

    var timer = setInterval(function () {
        var ps = page.evaluate(function () {
            document.body.bgColor = 'white';
            return document.getElementById("pageStatus").innerHTML;
        });


        if (!isLoad) {
            console.log("wait...");
            if (ps == "loaded") {
                clearInterval(timer);
                console.log("loaded");
                isLoad = true;
                page.render('new/exam.jpg');
                phantom.exit();
            }
        }
    }, 10);
}
});
```

Your help is highly appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: (1) Your `setInterval()` isn't doing anything, because you're not waiting for anything. `isLoad` is not changed outside of it. (2) How are you determining how to add the `transform` styles to the element? You need to provide that logic here in the question. We're not here to debug the JavaScript code on your page.

Comment: (1) setInterval() is ment for cases i want to do stuff like loading picture and wait for it to load and then set the form as "loaded" (2) you are right about the transform. the case was that i needed to set the style to -webkit-transform. after i did that it fixed the problem. thank you!